# ORA-12541: TNS:no listener - Oracle Instant Client

Tags: oracle, toad

I keep getting this error even though I'm sure I set up everything correctly, including the environment variables. I found a few posts on here, however, they were no help because apparently I don't even have any Oracle services to restart? Here are the files below:

TNSNAMES.ORA

```
REGQAT =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS =
          (COMMUNITY = tcp.world)
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)
          (Host = localhost)
          (Port = 1521)
        )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = REGQAT))
  )
```

sqlnet.ORA

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES)    
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN=WORLD
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8            
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
```

listener.ORA

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = regqat)
      (ORACLE_HOME = G:\Stuff\instantclient_19_11)
      (SID_NAME = REGQAT)
    )
  )
```

What I've tried:

1. Replacing `localhost` with `0.0.0.0`
2. Tried to restart oracle services but discovered I don't have any (no clue how)
3. Re-Checked Environment and System variables and made sure everything was in Place

I'm Using Oracle Instant client 19.11 and Toad. Whenever I try to ping `REGQAT` It says that no Listener was found.

Comment: OK, you installed a client. But, is there any **server** available to you? Because, the server is what runs the database itself. Just with a client, you can't do anything. As if you have a rifle, but no bullets.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this, please bear with me. Won't the server in this case be the localhost? or does that just mean its looking for a server hosted locally? So how do i set up a local oracle server

Comment: To rephrase myself: did you install the Oracle database? Computer that runs it is called a database "server". If you install the database on your own PC, i.e. "localhost", then yes - localhost *is* the database server. But the main question remains: did you install the database?

Comment: Here's a link: https://www.oracle.com/downloads/#category-database . If you're a beginner, perhaps Oracle 18c Express Edition (XE) would suffice.

Comment: I downloaded 19c is that okay?

Comment: I didn't see ur message and went searching

Comment: Any database would do. XE is the simplest, but still powerful enough.

Comment: Review https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/ora-12545-12541-12514-01017/